# No picture Display when try to retrieve image

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

My image at database didn't show up at window phone.
I only can get the EmpNo at the list, but the image didnt show up at my listbox.
Any wrong with my coding?

My coding at MainPage.xaml is

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <src:ImageConverter x:Key="imgConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox Height="650" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,17,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmpNo}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="16,16,0,0" Name="imgEmp" Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"
                Source="{Binding EmpImage}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

and my coding at mainpage.xaml.cs is

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Service1Client svc = new Service1Client();
        svc.GetAllModelsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetAllModelsCompletedEventArgs>(svc_GetAllModelsCompleted);
        svc.GetAllModelsAsync();
    }

    void svc_GetAllModelsCompleted(object sender, GetAllModelsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
}
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var empImage = new BitmapImage();
        empImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        empImage.SetSource(memStream);
        return empImage;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the converter:

```
Source="{Binding EmpImage, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"
```

Comment: thnx. but now had the other error invalidCastException was unhandled at var memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);

Comment: @Brownieyeo then your `value` can't be cast to a byte array.

Comment: @Brownieyeo I don't understand what you're saying, but please try to debug this issue yourself. Put a breakpoint in your converter and check why the `value` can't be converted to an image by inspecting all variables and stepping through the code.

Comment: The locals there show me for statice member CreateOptionsProperty Cannot fetch the value of field 'CreateOptionsProperty' because information about the containing class is unavailable. System.Windows.DependencyProperty
 &   UriSourceProperty Cannot fetch the value of field 'UriSourceProperty' because information about the containing class is unavailable. System.Windows.DependencyProperty.
What does it means?